# cordova3.5 Install phonertc plugin error

Tags: cordova, plugins, webrtc, phonertc

I found someting error when I install cordova plugin ,I run this command in my Cordova project directory.

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

Fetching plugin "https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git" via git clone
Error: Command failed: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___st
rlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```